# Build Tree structure Dynamically in View Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to create N - level Tree structure dynamically in View Ruby on rails? Mainly needed help in building logic to render tree structure.

Comment: What's the problem here?

Comment: yes, this question is vague: is rendering your problem? is passing variables from a controller to the view the problem? is dealing with basic collections in Ruby your problem? Show some more info please.

Comment: thanks for ur reply, u understood my problem, the problem is now  node.name and child.name are printing in console and i want them(child.name and node.name) to display in view(index.html.erb)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made use of [acts_as_tree](https://rubygems.org/gems/acts_as_tree/versions/2.4.0) ruby gem, which is very useful in getting parent and child nodes.

I created two partials named **_parent.html.erb** and **_child.html.erb**

those I rendered recursively as bellow.

**_parent.html.erb**

```
// root nodes - nodes having no parent

<%root_nodes.each do |root_node|%>
  <%= render :partial => "child", :object => root_node%>
<%end%>
```

**_child.html.erb**

```
// child nodes - nodes having parent

<%=child.name%>

child.children_nodes.each do |child_node|
  <%=render :partial => "child", :object => child_node %>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems somewhat overengineered.  The following will give you parent & child relationships in a single table:

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Node"
  has_one :child, :class_name => "Node", :foreign_key => :parent_id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing `node.name` but then you check if `node` is `nil` in the very next line. When `node` is already `nil`, `node.name` will throw `NoMethodError`.

Moral of the story: Write tests to make sure your application does not pass `nil` to `Recursion.traverse`.

Comment: thanks for reply, Check now i changed the code..my problem is not with logic ..problem is how can i display node.name and child.name in index.html.erb(HTML page), now they are displaying in console